# I am displaying a date picker in TextFormField,So date is perfectly coming in textFormfile, format-is 2019-11-12 00.00.0000-but i need 12-11-2019

Tags: flutter, dart, datepicker, dateformatter, textformfield

DateTime currentdate=new DateFormat.yMMMd().format(DateTime.now()) as DateTime;
TextEditingController _date=TextEditingController();

Future_selectDate(BuildContext context)async{

```
final DateTime? pickedDate=await showDatePicker(context: context, initialDate: currentdate, firstDate:DateTime(2015), lastDate: DateTime(2050),);

if(pickedDate!=null&&pickedDate!=currentdate)
  setState(() {

    currentdate=pickedDate;
    _date.value=TextEditingValue(text: pickedDate.toString());

  });
```

}

***/When using this format I have an error of - type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast**

Answer (score 1):

you can try this step

step 1:-  import the package intl.dart which used to get the local date and time.

```
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
```

step 2:- Now you can specify the format of date that you want like below

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
String formattedDate = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy – hh:mm').format(now);
```

now you can print the date and check in terminal you can find the date 12-11-2021 && if you want slash / like 12/11/2021 the  you can replace the dash - to /

Comment: When using this format I have an error of - type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'DateTime' in type cast